# CompletableFuture supplyAsync with Stream.map()

Tags: concurrency

guys! I have a question: what does this code do:

```
Collection<Contract.class> contracts = fillTheCollectionFromDb();
contracts.stream().filter(condition)
                  .map(contractItem ->
                       CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> 
                           {T result = getAnotherDataFromDb(contractItem); 
                            return result;}, Executor.class)
                  )//end .map
                  .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: which programming language is it? Looks like Java, but ".class" is used incorrectly in both cases.

Comment: Java+Spring Boot. Extention .class for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this code is equivalent to:

```
Collection<Contract> contracts = fillTheCollectionFromDb();
contracts.stream().filter(condition)
              .map(this::getAnotherDataFromDb)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To make this program truly parallel, it should be modified. First, launch all the requests to database in parallel:

```
Collection<Contract> contracts = fillTheCollectionFromDb();
List<CompletableFuture> futures = contracts.stream().filter(condition)
              .map(contractItem ->
                   CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                         ()->getAnotherDataFromDb(contractItem),
                       executor)
              )//end .map
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and only after that collect all the results:

```
List results = futures.stream
      .map(CompletableFuture::join)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you ...Solution was of great help to me. Can you also please show how to handle Exception if any of the futures has an exception.

Comment: For checked exception you can use get instead of join like below:
`List results =
        futures.stream()
            .map(
                future -> {
                  try {
                    return future.get();
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    throw new RuntimeException("");
                  } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("");
                  }
                });
            .collect(Collectors.toList());`